# How do I return top 2 maximum value from my code

Tags: java

How do I add to my code to find and return the top two values now that I have sorted it the array. I'm not sure on how to go to return the top 2 maximum values.

```
double[] Array = { 8.4, 9.3, 0.2, 7.9, 3.4};
Arrays.sort(doubleArray);
System.out.printf("%ndoubleArray: ");

for ( double  value : doubleArray) 
System.out.printf("%.1f ", value);
```

Comment: Please post your code *here*. You haven't attempted **anything**. Please show some effort

Comment: this is what i have done https://gyazo.com/86e06144817a2db2629ceff6b7496fd3

Comment: Please read the help section on how to ask a question. You need to provide the actual code here not on some outside link. Provide detail such as what you expect, what you are getting, and any errors.

Comment: Sorry I'm just learning how to use Stackoverflow, just edited my post!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
n = doubleArray.length;
double[] topTwo= new double[2];
topTwo[0] = doubleArray[n-1];
topTwo[1] = doubleArray[n-2];
return topTwo;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
double[] doubleArray = {8.4, 9.3, 0.2, 7.9, 3.4};
Arrays.sort( doubleArray );
double[] topTwo = {doubleArray[doubleArray.length - 1], doubleArray[doubleArray.length - 2]};
```

Comment: Not a problem @Patron